# Matlab Plotting Two Matrixes and Marking some X-Coordinates On it Based off another vector

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

Say I have two vectors I want to plot on matlab, and I have this vector that I want to use to mark a small "X" on the plot where this X-value occurs on one of the vectors, how do I do that?

To clarify, say I have a vector of `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` another of `b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and an identifier vector of `a = [1, 4]` how do I plot these and show an X on a/b on the plot on `x=1 and x =4`?

Comment: In the case of identifier vector, it is the same (you called both `a`), or is a `a_2=[1,4]` ?

Comment: As `a` and `b` have different sizes, you are plotting these vectors against something else or just the vectors itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, to find the points that you want, you can use the [`ismember` function](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) as show below.

```
a=1:5;
c=[1 4];
hold on
plot(a(~ismember(a,c)),'ro') %values of a that DO NOT match the extra entry
plot(a(ismember(a,c)),'rx') %values of a that match the extra entry
```

I'm not 100% clear if it is this what you want. You can give some comments and I (or someone else) can give you a better answer.

Comment: Perfect! I modified your code a bit but it did steer my 100% on the right way, thanks!